# MVC 4 WebGrid Checkbox in a column with Condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to add a new column to a .Net MVC WebGrid that includes a checkbox that is there if a specific condition is met and not there if the condition is false.

The below code works to correctly display X or Y (placeholder):

```
        grid.Column("ID", header: "", 
            style: "labelcolumn",
            format: (item) => item.ID != null ? "X" : "Y"),
```

I can't seem to get the syntax right to include the checkbox instead of X.

```
        grid.Column("ID", header: "", 
            style: "labelcolumn",
            format: (item) => item.ID != null ? @<text><input class="check-box" id="cbSelectedBranch" name="cbSelectedBranch" type="checkbox" value="@item.ID" /></text> : "Y"),
```

On this second snippet, the "(item)" variable causes this error:

> CS0136: A local variable named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope
>   because it would give a different meaning to 'item', which is already
>   used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Adding the @ when using the if null condition seems to cause item to throw this error. The below code, without the conditional, works correctly:

```
        grid.Column(header: "", 
            style: "labelcolumn",
            format: @<text><input class="check-box" id="cbSelectedBranch" name="cbSelectedBranch" type="checkbox" value="@item.ID" /></text>),
```

Any idea how I can make this work with a conditional and checkbox input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
format: (item) => item.ID != null ? Html.Raw("<input class='check-box' id='cbSelectedBranch' name='cbSelectedBranch' type='checkbox' value='@item.ID' />") : "Y")
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work right either. It does get around the " local variable named 'item' cannot be declared" but then it throws an error "Expression Expected" when it hits the @ symbol infront of the colon.

Comment: That second update doesn't throw any errors, but it renders the checkbox as the literal text instead of as a checkbox, ie it displays like this: 

<input class='check-box' id='cbSelectedBranch' name='cbSelectedBranch' type='checkbox' value='@item.ID' />

Comment: wrap it in Html.Raw and check

Comment: Thanks... that was close enough I got it to work. Both sides of the condition need to be wrapped in Html.Raw and how inserting the value had to be changed (because it was literally inserting the text @item.ID instead of the ID). Final version below:

`format: (item) => item.ID != null ? Html.Raw(string.Format("<input class='check-box' id='cbSelectedBranch' name='cbSelectedBranch' type='checkbox' value='{0}' />", @item.ID)) : Html.Raw("Y")`